# LINQ Dynamic field in .Where statement

Tags: c#

How to use dynamic field name in where statement?

example: I can use,

```
MyList.Where(x => x.Name == "MyName");
```

but how to use like this?

```
string MyField = "Name";
MyList.Where(x => MyField == "MyName");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `PropertyInfo` from `System.Reflection` and use its `GetValue()` method :)

```
PropertyInfo inf = typeof(YourClass).GetProperty("PropertyName");
MyList.Where(x => inf.GetValue(x) == "MyName");
```

For it to work, of course the variable `Name` should be a `Property` like so :

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Hope it helped :)

Comment: thanks for the reply, could you please write sample code?